# Add span around default wordpress category widget

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for a easy way to modify how wordpress output the category list in the widget section.

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-12 current-cat"><a href="https://mywebsite.com/pharmacotherapie-observance-adhesion-therapeutique/">Pharmacothérapie et observance et/ou adhésion thérapeutique</a>
```

I need to display it like this instead.

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-12 current-cat"><a href="https://mywebsite.com/category/pharmacotherapie-observance-adhesion-therapeutique/"><span style="display: block; margin: 0 0 0 20px;">Pharmacothérapie et observance et/ou adhésion thérapeutique</span></a>
```

I will prefers to do it inside my function.php file of my theme. I don't want to use jQuery or edit the wordpress core code.

Answer (score 0):

We need the original behavior of WordPress default text widget at many places within WordPress. For that reason, you have to create a custom text widget as WordPress plugin, then use it like the way you are currently using the default text widget.

It is very easy to create WordPress custom widget, just paste this on `functions.php` :

```
require_once("your_widget.php");
add_action("widgets_init", "your_custom_widgets_init");

function your_custom_widgets_init(){
  register_widget("Your_Custom_Widget_Class");
}
```

Then you have way to write CSS of it's own for list, instead of adding span class to force. You can do whatever as CSS of "Your_Custom_Widget" will be under your control.

Comment: I was thinking that only a str_replace function would have been easier to do inside the fonctions.php. What do you think? I know that we can alter the widget but I don't have a clue how to do it.

Comment: Yes, obviously you can use. That is actually under the hood of many WordPress plugins related to widgets. Like this -- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203176/str-replace-function-in-theme